# XCode Project with Library and App Debug Symbols

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, debug-symbols

I have a simple XCode project with a static library consumed by an iOS app.

When the iOS app crashes, I end up with a stack trace that goes into the library but I just get assembly, not my library's source.

Is there a way to symbolicate my project?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the librarys source, just create a subproject in your XCode project with it. Then add the reference in your main poject to link against the static library that it will be build automatically from XCode (for the architecture you use in your main project). After this you can directly debug and see crash symbols (even in the Crash Logs from TestFlight and AppStore Releases).

This is working with C, C++ and Objective-C librarys (compared). Never builded a Swift library but should be no problem aswell.